# AWK: User input textfile

Tags: awk, user-input

Is there any way to ask for user input with pure AWK language?

I want to create a program that when run, using: "awk -f my.awk" does the following:

1. Prints "Enter filename:"
2. takes the input, opens the file and for each line prints linenumber and the lines content.

I can achieve this without user input using "awk -f my.awk text.txt".
If my.awk contains:

```
{print NR, $n}
```

or just by running it directly in the terminal using:

```
awk '{print NR, $n}' text.txt
```

I know this is a really silly question, but i cannot find any info regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To give `awk` a bash variable, use `awk -v awk_var=$bash_var 'BEGIN{print awk_var}'`. I don't know how to set the file name.

Comment: To print a file with line numbers: `cat -n file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Tested with gawk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        printf "enter filename: "
        getline < "-"
        ARGV[1] = $0
        ARGC = 2
    }
    {print NR, $0}
'
```

ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to ask for user input with pure AWK language?

In short no this can not be done with pure `awk`.

I'd probably write a short wrapper script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter filename:"
read filename

awk -f my.awk "$filename"
```

Or choose another scripting language such as `python` or `perl`.